# Using Ruby 1.9.2 in development and REE in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Is there any incompatibilities between Ruby 1.9.2 and REE that I should be aware of?

I will be deploying a Rails 3 app and I read that REE uses a lot less resources. Any drawbacks?

Deployment machine:
16 GB disk
256 MB RAM

Using Phusion Passenger and NGinx
Ruby on Rails 3.0.3

Comment: It is nearly always better to use the same VM in development that is being used in production, be it Ruby or Java or whatever. Minimizes the source of problems that inevitably come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Adam. REE uses ruby 1.8 syntax. Switching between ruby 1.8 and 1.9 syntax is headache job. Both Ruby 1.9.2 and REE are good implementations of ruby. In general, Ruby 1.9.2 runs faster and REE uses less memory. But I think catching up with the trend is good for further development, so I prefer to ruby 1.9.2

Comment: I updated the question with more information about the deployment machine. So, given I am using Rails 3 and the development of Ruby going straight to 1.9 it will be convenient to use latest 1.9.

Comment: 256RAM is much less than the recommendation, so whatever VM you use, you need god(http://god.rubyforge.org/) to monitor your app in case of running out of memory. Actually I don't have any detail benchmark between 1.9.2 and REE. If your app's performance is important, you'd better run a small flare app on both of them, then you may find out the better one.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with rvm, and test how it works with both environments.

Give it a try, it should take less than 15 minutes and you'll be sure you have no problem.

- https://rvm.io/

Comment: I use it in my development machine. But is it a good idea to use it too in the production server? Any conflicts with Phusion passenger of NGinx?

Comment: I havent had any problems, you just have to set up your capistrano recipes according to it.